# How can I calculate the inertia tensor of a hollow object defined by a triangle mesh?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

I want to calculate the mass, center of mass, and inertia tensor of player created objects. Some of the objects will be hollow instead of solid. I am creating a closed triangle mesh for their object. Note that this is for a physics building game so I want the values to be as accurate as possible (within reason).

Based on the references listed below, I can get the properties for a solid object by creating a tetrahedron from each triangle of the mesh and calculating the signed volume which gives the mass (volume * density) and the center of mass. I even got the inertia tensor calculation working.

**How do I do the same for a hollow object?**

1. For the mass and center of mass, I am iterating through the triangles of the mesh and totaling their area and calculating the area-weighted average of their positions, then multiplying the surface area by a "density" value to get the mass.

   ```
    public static (float, Vector3) CalculateSurfaceArea(Mesh mesh)
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

        float totalArea = 0f;
        Vector3 temp = Vector3.zero;

        for (int i = 0; i <= triangles.Length - 3; i += 3)
        {
            Vector3 v1 = vertices[triangles[i]];
            Vector3 v2 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
            Vector3 v3 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];
            Vector3 edge21 = v2 - v1;
            Vector3 edge31 = v3 - v1;

            float area = Vector3.Cross(edge21, edge31).magnitude / 2f; // area of the triangle
            totalArea += area;

            Vector3 triCenter = (v1 + v2 + v3) / 3f; // center of the triangle
            temp += triCenter * area;
        }

        Vector3 areaCenter = temp / totalArea;

        return (totalArea, areaCenter);
    }
   ```
2. For the inertia tensor, I am trying a similar approach where I iterate through all the triangles and total up their moments of inertia and using the parallel-axis theorem to account for their positions but **(a) I am not sure this is correct** and **(b) how do I calculate the products of inertia (Ixy, Ixz, Iyz)?**

   ```
    public static (Vector3, Quaternion) CalculateHollowInertiaTensor(Mesh mesh)
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

        double Ixx = 0f;
        double Iyy = 0f;
        double Izz = 0f;
        double Ixy = 0f;
        double Ixz = 0f;
        double Iyz = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i <= triangles.Length - 3; i += 3)
        {
            Vector3 v1 = vertices[triangles[i]];
            Vector3 v2 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
            Vector3 v3 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];
            Vector3 edge21 = v2 - v1;
            Vector3 edge31 = v3 - v1;
            Vector3 center = (v1 + v2 + v3) / 3f; // center of the triangle
            Vector3 offset = center - v1;

            float area = Vector3.Cross(edge21, edge31).magnitude / 2f; // area of the triangle

            // Moment of inertia of triangle rotating around the first vertex
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia
            // I = (1/6)m(P.P + P.Q + Q.Q)
            float triIxx = (edge21.y * edge21.y + edge21.z * edge21.z + edge21.y * edge31.y + edge21.z * edge31.z + edge31.y * edge31.y + edge31.z * edge31.z) / 6f;
            float triIyy = (edge21.x * edge21.x + edge21.z * edge21.z + edge21.x * edge31.x + edge21.z * edge31.z + edge31.x * edge31.x + edge31.z * edge31.z) / 6f;
            float triIzz = (edge21.x * edge21.x + edge21.y * edge21.y + edge21.x * edge31.x + edge21.y * edge31.y + edge31.x * edge31.x + edge31.y * edge31.y) / 6f;

            // Shift to the center of the triangle
            triIxx -= offset.y * offset.y + offset.z * offset.z;
            triIyy -= offset.x * offset.x + offset.z * offset.z;
            triIzz -= offset.x * offset.x + offset.y * offset.y;

            // Shift to the origin (using parallel-axis theorem)
            triIxx += center.y * center.y + center.z * center.z;
            triIyy += center.x * center.x + center.z * center.z;
            triIzz += center.x * center.x + center.y * center.y;

            Ixx += triIxx * area;
            Iyy += triIyy * area;
            Izz += triIzz * area;
            //Ixy += area * center.x * center.y;
            //Ixz += area * center.x * center.z;
            //Iyz += area * center.y * center.z;
        }

        Matrix<double> inertiaTensor = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(3, 3);
        inertiaTensor[0, 0] = Ixx;
        inertiaTensor[1, 1] = Iyy;
        inertiaTensor[2, 2] = Izz;
        inertiaTensor[0, 1] = inertiaTensor[1, 0] = -Ixy;
        inertiaTensor[0, 2] = inertiaTensor[2, 0] = -Ixz;
        inertiaTensor[1, 2] = inertiaTensor[2, 1] = -Iyz;

        Debug.Log(inertiaTensor);

        //Matrix<double> inertiaTensorInverse = inertiaTensor.Inverse();

        // Find the principal axes and simplified inertia tensor
        Evd<double> evd = inertiaTensor.Evd();
        Vector3 inertiaTensorDiagonal = MakeVector3(evd.EigenValues.Real());
        Quaternion inertiaTensorRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(
            MakeVector3(evd.EigenVectors.Column(2)),
            MakeVector3(evd.EigenVectors.Column(1))
            );

        return (inertiaTensorDiagonal, inertiaTensorRotation);
    }
   ```

*References I have found so far:*

- How to calculate the volume of a 3D mesh object the surface of which is made up triangles
  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1406029
- List of moments of inertia
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia
- Polyhedral Mass Properties, David Eberly
  https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/PolyhedralMassProperties.pdf
- Explicit Exact Formulas for the 3-D Tetrahedron Inertia Tensor in Terms of its Vertex Coordinates, F. Tonon
  http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/sciencepublications/jmssp/2005/8-11.pdf

Comment: I can see that you are not using Mathematica for this, still it may be helpful at some point in your process, since you can pass graphic primitives and mesh regions to the function MomentOfInertia directly to get the result you want. See the Scope section in the [documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MomentOfInertia.html).